# Geometric interpretation of mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, standard-model, quantum-gravity, unified-theories

I have a question about the definition of mass. In general relativity mass is closely related the curvature of spacetime, which indicates that mass might be interpreted as a geometric concept (maybe related with the connection defined on some fibre bundle structures above spacetime). I found only Gonzalez-Martin's related work on this topic in his book "physical geometry".

Gonzalez-Martin's work was quite old and two of his papers related to this topic are:

- Physical Geometry: A Unified Theory of Gravitation, Electromagnetism and Other Interactions
- A Geometric Definition of Mass

His book including these two papers can be found here: [Physical geometry](http://prof.usb.ve/ggonzalm/invstg/pblc/phsclgmtr.pdf).

But I did not catch his idea. Can anybody help to explain his idea or provide other alternative work in this direction? BTW, I wonder if a geometric description of spacetime is valid, if the discrete space (~Planck length) somehow be related with the isoholonomic problem, which aims to find out the minimal loop to generate a given holonomy.

Comment: You should provide us with the ideas he presented. We aren't going to read through an entire book just to see *if* we can answer this question.

Comment: Mass is defined by inertia trough Newton's second law. General relativity _assumes_ that inertial mass and gravitating mass are the same. If that assumption is false, then there would have to be, at least, two different masses and it would not be clear, at this point, what the actual meaning of gravitating mass is, but it would definitely not be geometric, since the geometric aspects of general relativity are a direct consequence of the equivalence relation. Failing equivalence GR would become a true force theory with mass being an effective charge.

Comment: Unfortunately those links are paywalled, or require an institutional subscription. Sadly this is true for a lot of papers before the arxiv took off.  It's very hard to judge the content of the question without access to them (I personally find the idea attractive, but I was a classical GR person, so everything I think is wrong in suitable limits...).

Comment: @ CuriousOne The inertial mass defined by Newton's second law is essentially also defined by the space time structure, so it might also be 'geometric'. So it's natural to assume the equivalence principle.  We can not say if the equivalence relation is the reason or the consequence.

Comment: @ tfb I found a link of the book I mentioned at  http://prof.usb.ve/ggonzalm/invstg/pblc/phsclgmtr.pdf. Could you please have a try? thanks.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the comments. I updated my question with links to the papers/books.

Comment: @ CuriousOne  For me, if mass is geometric, then this might lead to the equivalence principle.

Comment: @X.Dong Mass is not geometry, mass and any other energy-like sources (momentum etc) determine the geometry, through Einstein. You can go to higher resolution, or energies, and maybe you sense the insides of elementary particles, and maybe they turn out to be strings or loops or or quantum gravity constructs. And then maybe those strings/etc maybe cause (however, not clear), spacetime, or if you wish geometry. But it is then clear that you need to have those strings/etc also account for the other forces, because you have energies that create spacetime and you've not accounted for them.

Comment: Need to either get deeper with some content, or ignore the issue. See my comment on the answer below on what might make sense.

Comment: @ Bob Bee  Thanks for the comments.  As you mentioned, mass/energy determine geometry by Einstein, but curvature is fully determined by connection, we can not be sure that mass is not geometry. Also Lloyd's computational universe proposal derives Einstein's equation purely from quantum computation, where the geometry side(metric/distance) is given by the casual structure of the QC and the energy side is given by the unitary operation(through phase change of each QC gate). So geometry and mass have the same root, a short distance means a slower computation and a smaller mass .

Answer (score 1):

I admit that what I write here is not a an answer to the question but rather a comment on the ideas of treating mass (or matter) in geometric terms.  Unfortunately, the comment feature has limited space so I am using this answer to voice these comments.

In the 1972 publication of Steven Weinberg's book "Gravitation and Cosmology -- Principles and Applications of the General Theory of Relativity", in the Preface Weinberg writes (April 1971) about his lament of the overemphasis (of authors) of the Geometrical approach to General Relativity, in particular he says

> However, I believe that the geometrical approach has driven a wedge between General Relativity and the theory of elementary particles.  As long as it could be hoped, as Einstein did hope, *that matter would eventually be understood in geometrical terms,* [Emphasis mine].

In addition, Weinberg writes

> ...it made sense to give Riemannian geometry a primary role in describing the theory of gravitation.  But now the passage of time has taught us not to expect that the strong, weak, and electromagnetic interactions can be understood in geometrical terms and too great an emphasis on geometry can only obscure the deep connections between gravitation and the rest of physics.

So, Einstein apparently had this notion that matter (or, mass) could be described in geometrical terms yet it was never a fulfilled work in his lifetime.  And, as far as I know, not fulfilled yet.  Einstein's belief in the geometric approach in describing natural laws of physics is what occupied him for many years chasing down the wrong path.

Comment: If it is not an answer don't write it in the answer box. Write a comment if you want, not a history of why some people like Einstein wanted to make mass or all of it geometric. There's already a reference in the question to somebody who published and wrote on it extensively. At least read something and try to answer what was the idea in the author's writing. It is much more than making matter geometric. It's making electromagnetism geometric and other things. It is complex enough that I don't know if I believe or understand it.

Comment: I can not fully catch the geometric meaning of the mass of Ganzalez-Martin.  It seems that mass is defined as a function of connection, but what exactly is mass's geometric picture?

Comment: @K7PEH Personally I would like not to regard gravity as a fundamental force, at least we have to admit it has a different structure with the other three forces.  It seems that gravity as the geometry of spacetime is emergent, for example from quantum mechanics.